# Conjecture: There is no $n\neq3$ such that $\arctan(1)+\arctan(2)+\cdots+\arctan(n)=\frac{k\pi}{2}$, with $k$ integer.

Tags: trigonometry, conjectures

Fact: $\arctan (1) + \arctan (2) + \arctan (3) = \pi$.

**Conjecture:** there is no $n \neq 3$ such that $\arctan (1) + \arctan (2) + \cdots + \arctan (n) = \frac{k\pi}{2}$, with $k$ integer.

I know a stronger result than conjecture is:
The product $(1 + 1^2) (1 + 2^2) \cdots (1 + n^2)$ is just a perfect square for $n = 3$

Comment: Can you explain how the result about the product implies the conjecture? It isn't obvious.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A180657](https://oeis.org/A180657) and linked article by Amdeberhan, Medina and Moll (the other link to Moll seems dead).

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243003820_Squares_in_121n21121n21

Comment: The article by Amdeberhan et al proves this by showing $\tan(\arctan(1) + \cdots \arctan(n))$ is well defined and never $0$.  But where did this problem come from if the OP was not aware of this paper?

Comment: There is also a nice combinatorial interpretation of $\tan(\arctan(x_1) + \cdots +\arctan(x_n))$ in terms of skew Schur polynomials.  See [Ardila-Serrano](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2219), Prop 3.4.

Comment: Explaining the product:
Consider an = (1 + 1i) (1 + 2i) ... (1 + ni).

Note that arg (an) = sum shown.
Now an is always a gauss integer.
In the desired case, where an = k or ki,
| an | = | k |, which should be integer
on the other hand, | an | = sqrt ((1 + 1 ^ 2) (1 + 2 ^ 2) ... (1 + n ^ 2))
So if such a product is not a perfect square, the modulus is not an integer, and an cannot be imaginary or pure real, with the sum different from some multiples of pi over 2.